# Bound on $\exp[-1/x]$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

How can I show that 
$e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \leq \frac{x}{e}$ on the interval $x\in[0,1]$ ?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval should be $(0,1]$. If you set $t=1/x$, the inequality becomes
$$
e^{-t}\le \frac{1}{et},\qquad \text{for $t\ge1$}
$$
or, as well,
$$
et\le e^t,\qquad \text{for $t\ge1$}
$$
Now consider $f(t)=e^t-et$ on $[1,\infty)$. Since $f(1)=0$ and
$$
f'(t)=e^t-e
$$
what can you conclude?

You can also do it by taking logarithms: your inequality is equivalent to
$$
-\frac{1}{x}\le \log x-1,\qquad\text{for $0<x\le1$}
$$
The function
$$
g(x)=\log x+\frac{1}{x}-1
$$
has $g(1)=0$ and its derivative is
$$
g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x-1}{x^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you @egreg.  I made a mess while trying to take a log on both sides.

Comment: @sefi You can do it with logarithms as well.